# Hover change background color but not change the text a color

Tags: html, css

This is my code, i only can change the "popup1_btn" button color when hover but text color cannot be changes. If using  `.popup1_btn a:hover`, it only change the text's background color and text color not the whole button's background color.

HTML

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal home-modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="get_free_modal">
       <div class="modal_top_logo">
          <img src="http://example.jpg">
       </div>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Close" class="modal-close close"><img src="http://example.png"></a>
       <div class="modal_inner_contant">
         <div class="third_modalImg">
            <img src="http://example.jpg">
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="popup1_btn">
         <a href="http://example.com/">I'm Interested</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.popup1_btn {
    width: 210px;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #d3db2c;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family:"Avant Garde Demi BT";
}

.popup1_btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: #d3db2c;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the line of code.

```
 .popup1_btn:hover a {
   color: #ffffff;
 }
```

Comment: happy to help, if it worked for you, could you select my answer as right one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
.popup1_btn:hover a {...}
```

```css
.popup1_btn {
    width: 210px;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #d3db2c;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family:"Avant Garde Demi BT";}


.popup1_btn:hover{
    background-color: black;
 }
 
 .popup1_btn:hover a {
    color: #d3db2c;
 }
```

```html
<div class="popup1_btn"><a href="http://example.com/">I'm Interested</a></div>
```